# Synth controls greyed out in Ableton Live 11

Tags: ableton-live

Utter noob here. A couple of weeks ago I created some basic tones using operator/synth lead, exported them as WAVs and that was that. I've now changed laptop and have re-opened the Live project to make some tweaks on the new laptop. Now, the synth controls I'd normally use to modify frequency etc (bottom panel) are 'greyed out' and I can't work out why. Both laptops have used Live 11 Trial. Help!

[image: Synth controls greyed out]

Answer (score 3):

Facepalm: I'd somehow managed to 'freeze' the track and solved this by right-clicking on the track and clicking 'unfreeze'.